# Viewstub not displacing adjacent views once inflated. Solution?

Tags: android, xml, android-inflate, viewstub

I have a ViewStub inside a DrawerLayout, and I plan to inflate and remove this stub dynamically according to the needs of the user.

The drawer consists of a RelativeLayout containing:
1. A TextView
2. The mentioned ViewStub
3. A ListView

When I inflate the ViewStub, the resulting view does not displace the ListView. Instead, it's inflated underneath the ListView, in such a way that the user can't see it. I would like for the stub to push the list down when it is inflated.

How can I solve this?

Here is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#dedede"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/info_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout="@layout/info_entry_stub"
            android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_text"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawernavlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/info_stub"
            android:layout_gravity="start">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The layout the stub points to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/info_entry_stub">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="HELLO"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**SOLUTION FOUND:** I solved it by adding inside the ViewStub the attribute:

```
android:inflatedId="@id/info_stub"
```

Answer (score 1):

Too late! but just for those who might ran into the same problem.

Once you inflate the `ViewStub` it will get removed from the view tree hierarchy, then its `id` won't exits. Therefore, there is no view in the layout with `"@+id/info_stub"` id, and your `ListView` wants to be below that (which does not exits)

You can either use a `LinearLayout`, or use `android:inflatedId="@+id/info_layout"` in your `ViewStub` and add `android:layout_below="@+id/info_layout"` to your `ListView`